# Getting ERROR:500 while adding multiple objects in modelviewset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to add multiple users using modelviewset but i got status code 500
i did some research but it seems not working, i did overwrite the create method with many=True, and also in serializer i did overwrite **init** function

Here is my view.py;

```
class StudentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = StudentSerializer
   permission_classes = (UserAccessPermissions,)

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(
         data=request.data, many=True)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

       # problem is here with perform_create i think
       self.perform_create(serializer)
   
       headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
       return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

   def get_queryset(self):
       username = self.request.user
       user = User.objects.get(username=username)
       if user.is_teacher:
          teacher = Teacher.objects.get(username=username)
          students = Student.objects.filter(
            department_name__in=teacher.department_name.all(), college_name=user.college_name)
       elif user.is_collegeAdmin:
          students = Student.objects.filter(college_name=user.college_name)
       return students
```

and serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(UserSerializer):
   department = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_department_name')
   batch = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_batch_name')
   college = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_college_name')

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
      super(StudentSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

   class Meta:
      model = Student
      fields = "__all__"
```

postman body;

```
[{
    "college_name": "3d1f82fb-c2db-41f1-9dea-8d875009355f",
    "enrollment_no": "8520258585852",
    "username": "student",
    "full_name": "studentbhai",
    "mobile_no": "+918520852001",
    "Date_of_Birth": "2000-10-05",
    "password": "Stu@1234",
    "email": "student@gmail.com",
    "department_name": "1",
    "batch_name": "1"
},
{
    "college_name": "3d1f82fb-c2db-41f1-9dea-8d875009355f",
    "enrollment_no": "8520258585852",
    "username": "student2",
    "full_name": "studentbhai",
    "mobile_no": "+918520852001",
    "Date_of_Birth": "2000-10-05",
    "password": "Stu@1234",
    "email": "student2@gmail.com",
    "department_name": "1",
    "batch_name": "1"
}]
```

Comment: A HTTP500 code typically means there was a server error. Check your local development webserver logs for what the actual error is.

Comment: yes you are right but if i pass single object rather than list of objects then its working fine, its throwing me error when i try to create multiple objects

Comment: I think you should try bulk_create https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create